# Return two objects to Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm doing a `RESTful` poll app and would like to return the question and answers in one request. I am able to access both objects in the rails app view but I only receive one (the question) with my ajax request. The idea is that I would have a separate app hitting this poll api.

Models:

```
class PollAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll_question
end

class PollQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :poll_answer
end
```

Controller:

```
def show
    @poll_question = PollQuestion.find(params[:id])
    @poll_answers = @poll_question.poll_answer

    # Tried this but it didn't work
    # @poll = {@poll_question.body => {:answers => @poll_answers.body}}
end
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
       url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/poll_questions/5.json",
       success: function(html){    
         console.log(html);
      }
  });
```

This is the json returned:

```
{"id":5,"body":"What was the best scene from The Legend of Ron Burgundy","created_at":"2014-02-04T17:04:31.264Z","updated_at":"2014-02-04T17:04:31.264Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to return it by writing custom controller code.

```
def show
    @poll_question = PollQuestion.find(params[:id])
    render json: { @poll_question.as_json({
            only: [:id, :body],
            include: {
                poll_answers: {
                    only: [:body]
                }
            }
        })
    }
end
```